# Strange df (disk space) output since macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, filesystem, catalina

Why is this:

```
$ df -h /
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5  234Gi   10Gi   15Gi    41%  482117 2448643243    0%   /
```

Very different from this:

```
$ df -h .
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1  234Gi  205Gi   15Gi    94% 1911870 2447213490    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
```

Is there an explanation with this new "data" filesystem? How is it different?